# First form required in formset

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, formset

I want to make first form in formSet required. I am trying to achieve it in `__init__` method of formset class, but it does not work. I am getting this error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
```

When i am using formset_factory instead of modelformset_factory everything is okay.
View:

```
form_class =  modelformset_factory(EventTime, form = EventTimeForm, extra=3, formset=EventTimeFormset)
formset = form_class(self.request.POST or None, prefix="form", instance = self.object)
```

Form:

```
class EventTimeFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        if not self.forms[0].cleaned_data['start_time']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("At least 1 time is required for event")    
            code = "missing_time"
```

Comment: Please show the entire traceback. Passing `instance = self.object` to a model formset looks strange to me - I didn't think they accepted `instance` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try `min_num` and `validate_min` like this -

```
form_class =  modelformset_factory(EventTime, form = EventTimeForm, extra=3, formset=EventTimeFormset, min_num=1, validate_min=True)
```

This will automatically validate for at least one formset factory item.

Documented here -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#validate-min